# proper way to dynamically assign backbone.js view el

Tags: backbone.js

I would like to create two ( or more ) view instances, each with different el attributes, and have events bound to them via backbone.js view's events hash ( not through jQuery ).

Getting events to trigger when all instantiations have the same `el` is easy:

```
someView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#someDiv',

  events: {
    'click': 'someFunction'
  },

  someFunction: function(){
    //Do something here
  }
});
```

So far, if I assign `el` in the `initialize` function, and set `events` normally as follows, events do not trigger:

```
someView = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    'click': 'someFunction'
  },

  initialize: function( options ){
    this.el = options.el
  },

  someFunction: function(){
    //Do something here
  }
});
```

My first instinct was to have `el` be a function that returns the string representation of the dom element of interest:

```
someView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: function(){
    return '#someDiv-' + this.someNumber
  },

  events: {
    'click': 'someFunction'
  },

  initialize: function( options ){
    this.someNumber = options.someNumber
  },

  someFunction: function(){
    //Do something here
  }
});
```

However, this triggers `someFunction` x times if I have x instantiations of `someView`.

Next I tried setting both the `el` and `events` attributes in `initialize`:

```
someView = Backbone.View.extend({

  initialize: function( options ){
    this.el = options.el
    this.events = {
      'click': 'someFunction'
    }
  },

  someFunction: function(){
    //Do something here
  }
});
```

but this does not trigger events.  At this point I'm pretty much fishing.

Does anyone know how instantiate a backbone.js view with an `el` specific to that instance that has events that only trigger for that instance, and not other instances of the `View`?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You don't actually need to go through all that "this.element" stuff.

Backbone automatically sets the view's "el" to the "el" you pass into the constructor as an option.

It is then available as "this.el" throughout the view.

This is all you need to do:

```
x = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
      'click': 'say_hi'
    },

    initialize: function( options ){
        // Not actually needed unless you're doing something else in here
    },

    say_hi: function(){
      alert( this.el.id );
    }

  });

y = new x( {el: '#div-1'} );
z = new x( {el: '#div-2'} );

z.say_hi();
y.say_hi();
​
```

See this live jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/edwardmsmith/QDFwf/15/

The reason your second example did not work is that with the latest versions of Backbone, you cannot just set the "el" directly any more.  This does not, as you noticed, properly set/update events.

**Does not work**

```
initialize: function( options ){
  this.el = options.el;
}
```

If you wanted to set the el dynamically that way, you need to use [View.setElement](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement) as that properly delegates events and sets up the cached [this.$el](http://backbonejs.org/#View-$el).

**Works**

```
initialize: function( options ){
  this.setElement(options.el)
}
```

Live jsFiddle of your second example: http://jsfiddle.net/edwardmsmith/5Ss5G/21/

But this is just re-doing what is already being done under the hood in Backbone.

Comment: Updated the two jsfiddles to source underscore and backbone from CDNjs instead of from github.

Assuming that was the issue you were seeing.