# Backbone View Default $el

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views

I looked up for proper way of assigning `el` to the view dynamically, [and found this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210438/proper-way-to-dynamically-assign-backbone-js-view-el)
According to this post, I'm passing `el` element while creating the view.

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
        options = options || {};

        this.$el = this.$el || $(".somediv ul");
    }
});
```

And then I create view like this:

```
// creating a view this way works fine.
this.myView= new MyView({
   'el': this.$('.someotherdiv ul')
});
```

This way of view creation works as expected. but there is a problem when I don't pass any `el` value to it.

```
//there is a problem though, If I create view like this: 
this.myView= new MyView();
```

`view.el` is not set to `$(".somediv ul")` instead it's just a div tag.

Can anyone tell me what is the right way of assigning `el` dynamically and setting a default value to it.

Comment: Why do you want to set `el` dynamically? Don't get this as criticism, I'd like to understand your use case. I use `el` in the view definition for example for "root" or "application views" that are bound to e.g. `body` or as argument during instantiation for decorative views that need to be bound to an existing element. I never came across a situation where I needed to set `el` after instantiation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by default, backbone view's `el` is set to an empty div. so, `this.el` and `this.$el` are always present.

<strike>you can probably try this:</strike>

```
 initialize: function (options) {
     options = options || {};
     this.$el = options.el ? $(options.el) : $('.somediv ul');
 }
```

but usually i wouldn't do this. You are coupling your view with the ".somediv ul" element on the page. :/

=============== EDIT ==================

Yea, there's a simpler solution. (silly me)

in your view:

```
  YourView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.somediv ul',

    initialize: function () {
    }
  });
```

`this.el` will be set to `.somediv ul` unless you pass a different one.

Comment: this seems like a little hacky way of doing it though, doesn't look natural. I'd like to think that there is an easy way of setting a default.

Comment: how come this is more hacky than your version? :)

Comment: mine is ofcourse hacky, hence the question on how to improve it :P

Comment: "usually i wouldn't do this" really should be "I would never do this, I would use `setElement`".

Comment: yea i thought about taht. :) `setElement` makes sure taht events are delegated properly.