# How do i pass a received array into underscore template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am getting a long array from PHP containing various data objects.

```
[{"commid":"1","uid":"0","pid":"3","comment":"comm","parid":null,"date":"2016-10-27 15:03:10"},
{"commid":"2","uid":"0","pid":"10","comment":"Ana","parid":null,"date":"2016-10-27 15:03:51"},
{"commid":"3","uid":"0","pid":"5","comment":"asss!","parid":null,"date":"2016-10-27 15:05:50"},
{"commid":"4","uid":"0","pid":"10","comment":"Lawl?","parid":null,"date":"2016-10-27 17:03:59"},
{"commid":"5","uid":"0","pid":"14","comment":"sd","parid":null,"date":"2016-11-06 00:25:04"},
{"commid":"6","uid":"0","pid":"14","comment":"sds","parid":null,"date":"2016-11-06 00:25:50"},
{"commid":"7","uid":"0","pid":"14","comment":"WOW!","parid":null,"date":"2016-11-08 15:06:18"},
{"commid":"8","uid":"0","pid":"13","comment":"Hello!?","parid":null,"date":"2016-11-08 15:14:30"}]
```

My Backbone View which will be rendering the data is

```
var WorkPage = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#indexcontent'),
    render: function() {
        Backbone.history.navigate('work');
        var _this = this;

        this.$el.html(workHTML);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "includes/server_api.php/work",
            data: '',
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                console.log(html);
                var compiledTemplate = _.template($('#content-box').html(), html);
                _this.$el.html(compiledTemplate);
            },
            error: function(e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

My workHTML which will be rendered by Underscore is

```
<script type="text/template" id="content-box">
<div class="workhead">
    <h3 class="msg comment"><%= comment%></h3>
    <p class="date"><%= date%></p>
</div>
</script>
<div id="content-box-output"></div>
```

How do I implement a underscore loop here?

Comment: The 'html' parameter you receive in the success handler is actually already JSON. So what you probably want to do is `_.each(html, function(record) {...` in the success handler. I'd suggest renaming the html parameter to results also

Comment: either i dont understand how you told me to usee _.each in success or its not working. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take advantage of Backbone's features. And to do that, you need to understand how to use a REST API with Backbone.

[**Backbone's Model**](http://backbonejs.org/#Model) is made to manage a single object and handle the communication with the API (`GET`, `POST`, `PATCH`, `PUT` requests).

[**Backbone's Collection**](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection) role is to handle an array of model, it handles fetching it (`GET` request that should return a JSON array of objects) and it also parse each object into a Backbone Model by default.

Instead of hard-coding a jQuery `ajax` call, use a Backbone collection.

```
var WorkCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: "includes/server_api.php/work",
});
```

Then, modularize your views. Make an item view for each object of the array you received.

```
var WorkItem = Backbone.View.extend({
    // only compile the template once
    template: _.template($('#content-box').html()),
    render: function() {

        // this is how you pass data to the template
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));

        return this; // always return this in the render function
    }
});
```

Then your list view looks like this:

```
var WorkPage = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.itemViews = [];
        this.collection = new WorkCollection();

        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);

        // this will make a GET request to
        // includes/server_api.php/work
        // expecting a JSON encoded array of objects
        this.collection.fetch({ reset: true });
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.empty();
        this.removeItems();
        this.collection.each(this.renderItem, this);
        return this;
    },

    renderItem: function(model) {
        var view = new WorkItem({
            model: model
        });
        this.itemViews.push(view);
        this.$el.append(view.render().el);
    },
    // cleanup to avoid memory leaks
    removeItems: function() {
        _.invoke(this.itemViews, 'remove');
        this.itemViews = [];
    }

});
```

It's unusual to set the url in the render function, you should keep the responsibilities scoped to the right place.

The router could be something like:

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        'work': 'workPage'
    },

    workPage: function() {
        var page = new WorkPage({
            el: $('#indexcontent'),
        });
    }
});
```

Then, if you want to see the work page:

```
var myRouter = new Router();

Backbone.history.start();

myRouter.navigate('#work', { trigger: true });
```

## Templates and RequireJS

> My `index.html` page contains this
>   `indexcontent` div but the `content-box` which contains the template
>   format which we are compiling is stored in different `work.html`. So,
>   if i dont load this `work.html` in my main `index.html` i am unable to
>   access `content-box`.

I would recommend to use the [text require.js plugin](https://github.com/requirejs/text) and load each template for the view like this:

The work-item.js file:

```
define([
    'underscore', 'backbone',
    'text!templates/work-item.html',
], function(_, Backbone, WorkItemTemplate) {
    var WorkItem = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: _.template(WorkItemTemplate),
        /* ...snip... */
    });
    return WorkItem;
});
```

The work-page.js file:

```
define([
    'underscore', 'backbone',
    'text!templates/work-page.html',
], function(_, Backbone, WorkPageTemplate) {
    var WorkPage = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: _.template(WorkPageTemplate),
    });
    return WorkPage;
});
```

Comment: Hey Emile, i understand what you're trying to say. And i tried to implement it too. But i couldnt understand the passing of el since i ma using require js. Can you take a look at this skeleton code and guide me to implement models and collections? Id really appreciate it. https://sizil@bitbucket.org/sizil/backbone-requireboiler.git

Comment: Could you have a look at above code? (link in comment)? thanks.

Comment: @unkn0wn it would be too long to explained in comments and out of scope for this thread. You should check the [doc](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el) and if it's not enough, you should ask a new question. But check first if there are already similar questions.

Comment: @unkn0wn [more info on `el`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210438/proper-way-to-dynamically-assign-backbone-js-view-el).

Comment: Its a very small problem. My `index.html` page contains this `indexcontent` div but the `content-box` which contains the template format which we are compiling is stored in different `work.html`. So, if i dont load this `work.html` in my main `index.html` i am unable to access `content-box`.

Comment: @unkn0wn I updated my answer but it's beginning to be way too long.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127661/discussion-between-unkn0wn-and-emile-bergeron).

Answer (score 2):

In your index.html file you need to have `_.each()` method to iterate throught each element

```
<% _.each(obj, function(elem){ %>
<div class="workhead">
    <h3 class="msg comment"><%= elem.comment %></h3>
    <p class="date"><%= elem.date%></p>
</div>
<% }) %>
```

I make variable of your response just to have data to work with. In your View you need to set point on template 
`template: _.template($("#content-box").html())`, and in render method just send data as object.

Here is working code : [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lybphcjv/)

Comment: I am using requireJS so this was giving me declaration error. This was the optimal solution otherwise, which i was trying to implement.

Comment: This would work, you just need to pass the data to the template by calling `this.template(receivedArray)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to load the template for each value in the data array.

```
var WorkPage = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#indexcontent'),
    render: function() {
        Backbone.history.navigate('work');
        var _this = this;

        this.$el.html(workHTML);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "includes/server_api.php/work",
            data: '',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                var $div = $('<div></div>');
                _.each(data, function(val) {
                    $div.append(_.template($('#content-box').html(), val));
                });
                _this.$el.html($div.html());
            },
            error: function(e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks man! I completely forgot about using _.each in my View. I had to use `JSON.parse(data)` though.

Comment: Glad I could help. I like @t_dom93 's answer though. It delegates responsibility to the template.

Comment: For the last many hours i was trying to solve using @t_dom93 's method. But since i am using requireJS i have no idea how to pass the variable in html. It wasn't reading variable name in my workHTML page.

Comment: That is really inefficient, far from the _Backbone_ way. It would be too long in a comment to list all the wrong things in this.

Comment: hey @EmileBergeron, I agree, it's not the approach I would take, but the answer is correct for the question, SO discourages questions/answers which are opinion-based.

Comment: @mikeapr4 There is no opinion to be had here, this answer is just not correct on many levels. It works doesn't make it a good answer. To be a good answer on SO, you must take good practices into account and steer away from the wrong direction OP might be heading.

Comment: @mikeapr4 a good answer must be useful for more than just OP. SO is not a Q&A for specific user's problems, it's a Q&A for a wider audience. That's one reason wiki-like _edits_ are encouraged.

Comment: So you think your answer with Backbone best practices under a question entitled 'How do I pass PHP's JSON_ENCODE array into underscore loop' will reach a wider audience? I won't deny your answer is very good and certainly helpful, but it wasn't requested and you have detracted from the answer which directly addresses the question

Comment: @mikeapr4 a question is also meant for a wider audience and even if worded that way, *it doesn't need what's asked for. It needs directions.* And it should be edited to reflect the real problem OP is having.

Comment: @mikeapr4 OP thinks he needs to pass an array to `_.each` but that's only because he's blinded by his objective and the current state of his code.