# Prevent that setting a row model attribute trigger a complete view render

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have a collection view that contains multiple row models that are rendered as table.

I have a templateHelper that is triggered when clicking on a checkbox (inside the table row). There, I set the model's models attribute e.g.:

```
this.model.set('autostart', true);
```

This triggers the complete remove and rendering of the collectionView.

**Is it possible (good practice) to only render only the single table row?**

Comment: Associate each row with its individual model. Then modifying a specific row should trigger a change specific to row itself. This is in-fact the best practice. Check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40488041/how-do-i-pass-a-received-array-into-underscore-template/40490074#40490074)  for row level model association.

Comment: While WinterSoldier's comment is right, his post doesn't use best practices. I highly encourage you to check the other answers.

Comment: _"Is it possible"?_ The answer is **yes**. Please include a [mcve] and we'll try to help from what you have.

Comment: @Emile Bergeron - I wasn't recommending him my answer by any means. I was infact referring him to your answer on that post. That is by far the best explanation I found. If you find my answer distracting on the post (although that's one quick-cheat to get it working as far as that question is concerned)- please go ahead and remove it.